# Mean of bimodal histogram (python)

Tags: python, histogram, mean, data-fitting

I am learning python and i need help. 
I have a data represents with histogram.Bimodal histogram(two peak).*I want to find mean* value of first peak (only first peak).First peak can be fitted with Gauss.

for example

[image: for example]

Thanks very much.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, update post

Comment: A problem with calculating the mean of the first peak is that you don't know when the first peak's tail is done and the second peak's tail is starting. Please take a look at our sister site, Cross-Validated. Someone asked a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5960/how-to-identify-a-bimodal-distribution . The answers show how to *identify* a bimodal data set.